# Add link button from InnerHtml

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a list item where it shows a tab and a link button:

```
<li runat="server" id="liActivityInvoices"><a href="#tabActivityInvoices">Invoices</a><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLoadInvoice" OnClick="btnInvoiceActivity_Click"  CssClass="btnListSmall" Width="90px"></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

[image]

In the code behind it searches for invoices and gets the total revenue. This then updates the list item to show the currency and revenue in the tab:

```
liActivityInvoices.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"#tabActivityInvoices\">Invoices (" + Company.Current.DefaultCurrency + ": " + Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TotalRev"]) + ")</a> <asp:LinkButton runat=\"server\" ID=\"btnLoadInvoice\" OnClick=\"btnInvoiceActivity_Click\"  CssClass=\"btnListSmall\" Width=\"90px\"></asp:LinkButton>";
```

[image]

The `a href` part is showing but the link button disappears. How can I show the link button using the InnerHtml?

Comment: This one is duplicate may be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053217/adding-a-asp-control-to-page-from-code-behind-within-innerhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkButton is a server control. You can't create server controls using inner html. You will have to instead add the control as a child control to liActivityInvoices.

```
var anchor = new LiteralControl("<a href=\"#tabActivityInvoices\">Invoices (" + Company.Current.DefaultCurrency + ": " + Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TotalRev"]) + ")</a>");
var lnkButton = new LinkButton
{
    ID = "btnLoadInvoice",
    CssClass = "btnListSmall",
    Width = new Unit("90px")
};
lnkButton.Click += btnInvoiceActivity_Click;
liActivityInvoices.Controls.Add(anchor);
liActivityInvoices.Controls.Add(lnkButton);
```

Comment: How do I add a child control?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Ok that shows the link button but there is an issue when I click on the button I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: btnInvoiceActivity_Click is not defined`

Comment: Yes it is a sever method `protected void btnInvoiceActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`. I tried your updated answer but still getting the same error

Comment: Is the method not accessible from where this code is defined?

Comment: When I click the button it reloads the page, which is causing the issue here, because it's not calling the method

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is a DOM element's property and hence case sensitive.
Modify your code as `liActivityInvoices.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: The property here is of a server control (asp.net) and not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add ASP.NET server controls as string literals.

Use `PlaceHolder` to add the dynamic server control or use add the control as a child control to `liActivityInvoices` or you can create `DivIndirizzo`